# jquery gallery / carousel oddity

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an image viewer that combines a thumbnail/large image block that works great...

looks like this:

```
<div id="gallery-large" ><img id="largeImage" src="" /></div>
<div id="gallery-scroller" >
    <ul class="holder">
    <li class="slide first"><img src="galleries/kids/01.jpg" data-large="galleries/kids/06.jpg" alt="1st image description" /></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="galleries/kids/02.jpg" data-large="galleries/kids/07.jpg" alt="2nd image description" /></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="galleries/kids/03.jpg" data-large="galleries/kids/08.jpg" alt="3rd image description" /></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="galleries/kids/04.jpg" data-large="galleries/kids/09.jpg" alt="4th image description" /></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="galleries/kids/05.jpg" data-large="galleries/kids/10.jpg" alt="5th image description" /></li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<script>
$('.holder').delegate('img','click', function(){
$('#largeImage').attr( 'src',$(this).attr('data-large') );
});
</script>
```

However when I try to combine this with a carousel (the simplest one I found here - http://www.flintstudio.biz/stuff/sliders/1.html )

It stops working...

the code looks like this

```
<div id="gallery-large" ><img id="largeImage" src="" /></div>
<div id="gallery-scroller" >
    <a class="button prev" ><img src="images/arrow_left.png"/></a>
    <a class="button next" ><img src="images/arrow_right.png"/></a>
        <ul class="holder">
            <li class="slide first"></li>
            <li class="slide"></li>
            <li class="slide"></li>
            <li class="slide"></li>
            <li class="slide"></li>
        </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>  

<script>
$( window ).load(function(){
    var images = ['galleries/kids/01.jpg', 'galleries/kids/02.jpg', 'galleries/kids/03.jpg', 'galleries/kids/04.jpg', 'galleries/kids/05.jpg'];     

    $.preloadImages( images, init );

    function init() {
        $( '#gallery-scroller' ).imgSlider( images );
    }

$('.holder').delegate('img','click', function(){
    $('#largeImage').attr( 'src',$(this).attr('data-large') );
});
});
</script>
```

from a concept standpoint the only difference is that the list is populated after the window loads - 
I've tried changing

```
.delegate('img','click', function(){
```

to

```
.on( 'click', 'img', finction(){
```

but that doesn't help..

OH - one important point - I changed one line in the carousel.js - so it's not doing a background-image css change, but adding an image...

so I changed this (line 37)

```
$( e ).find( '.holder > li' ).eq( i ).css( 'background', 'url('+images[i]+') no-repeat' );
```

to

```
$( e ).find( '.holder > li' ).eq( i ).html( '<img class="thumb" src="' + images[i] + '" />' );
```

What am I missing...???

jsfiddle of the simple thumbnail viewer... http://jsfiddle.net/cBpvZ/

jsfiddle of the carousel version... http://jsfiddle.net/ZJzLd/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are binding the events on wrong DOM object, so instead of IMG it should be LI. You can inspect the HTML using firebug and can see that there is no IMG tag inside UL.holder. Try the following code.

```
$('.holder').delegate('li','click', function(){
    var imgSrc = $(this).css('background-image').replace('url("','').replace('")','');
    $('#largeImage').attr( 'src',imgSrc);
});
```

Ideally I should have used the RegExp to replace the string, however this works.

Comment: thx.. I changed the carousel/js to insert an image NOT use css background... so I'll try your suggestion but look at my added code above..

Comment: @jpmyob: It would be of great help if you can share the code on fiddle.

Comment: done  although Im not sure how to add the carousel.js, so i just passed it in the js box, along with the onload...

Comment: @jpmyob: check this http://jsfiddle.net/cBpvZ/1/ . I have a question over here what is data-large ?

Comment: it's just a value that I'm passing so I could refer to ANY image - the way the original worked... (http://workshop.rs/demo/gallery-in-4-lines/) it ASSUMED the thumbnail would use "_thum"b and the large image would use "_large"... it did a replace (like your first example)... but I don't want to name/rename images... so I'm passing that "extra" data as an attribute that I can refer to - this way the large image can be named something totally different than the thumb... personal preference really

Comment: $(this).attr('data-large') will always return you undefined, as per the fiddle you shared there is not attribute called data-large. Could you please check this out.

Answer (score 0):

thx  Mahesh

forest thru the trees... I couldn't see it because I'd fiddled with it so much... the missing reference to data-large was indeed the issue.

the solution was (defined by me) to have TWO arrays - one for thumbs and one for large..(I could take the path of adding some suffix or prefix to the image names and keep them correlated that way - but I choose not to - and therefor want the flexibility to name things whatever... and this needs two arrays)

```
var images = ['galleries/kids/01.jpg', 'galleries/kids/02.jpg', 'galleries/kids/03.jpg', 'galleries/kids/04.jpg', 'galleries/kids/05.jpg'];
var large = ['galleries/kids/06.jpg', 'galleries/kids/07.jpg', 'galleries/kids/08.jpg', 'galleries/kids/09.jpg', 'galleries/kids/10.jpg'];

$('#gallery-scroller').append('<img src="images/loader.gif" id="gallery-loader" style="position:absolute; top:45%; left:45%;"/>');

$.preloadImages( images, init );

function init() {
$( '#gallery-loader' ).remove();
$( '#gallery-scroller' ).imgSlider( images, large );
}
```

of course this mean altering the carousel.js to handle the additional passed array - no prob there...

works like a charm. I can now populate this with data, and place the carousel anywhere I need, and the large image viewer where I need it... bravo - thanks for the assist.